# How to parse an address string to street and house number

Tags: regex, pandas, string, parsing

So I want to separate the street and house number from the address line. I can split the address based on the last space (my code below). But this won't help for the case in line 3, where the house number actually contains space.

```
address             street          house_number
my street 6         my street       6
my street 10a       my street       10a
next street 5 c     next street     5 c
next street100      next street     100
```

My best try, which does not help with the 3rd case:

```
df['street'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split(' ')[:-1]))
df['house_number'] = df['address'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1])
```

My idea would be: identify the first digit (number) in the string and split the string in 2 parts from there. Regex? I tried but no solution

Code for reproduction

```
data = {'address': ['my street 6', 'my street 10a', 'next street 5 c', 'next street100'],
        'street': ['my street', 'my street', 'next street', 'next street'],
        'house_number': ['6', '10a', '5 c', '100']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

EDITED: 4th case added

Comment: There are many different formats of addresses, this is not very easy. If you really need to do this, you should make the user fill in different fields in the form.

Comment: You might be interested in this https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#postal-addresses

Comment: @Barmar Agree. And dealing with addresses is such a pain in my experience. I separate the addresses in group and this is one among many groups. So let's consider this question to be specific to the example I gave.

Comment: Before you can create any code, including a regular expression, you must be able to describe the rules for what you are trying to do.  So your first problem is deciding what the rules of an address are.

Comment: I did give a rule by describing my idea how I tried to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do; Use .str.split() to split by the space that comes before the digit

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'address':['my street 6','my street 10a','next street 5 c']})
```

Solution

```
df.address.str.split('\s(?=\d)', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'street',1:'house_number'})
```

Outcome

```
      street        house_number
0    my street            6
1    my street          10a
2  next street          5 c
```

If you wanted to include the original column. Please try;

```
df1=df.join(df.address.str.split('\s(?=\d)', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'street',1:'house_number'}))



        address       street     house_number
0      my street 6    my street            6
1    my street 10a    my street          10a
2  next street 5 c  next street          5 c
```

RegEx explaination

The RegEx looks for the position of the space (\s), with a condition (?= ) that a digit (\d) would follow it (?=\d)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This article helped me understand the RegEx. I added the explaination in your answer. https://bioinfomagician.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/regular-expression-tutorial-1-special-characters/

Comment: I added the 4th case, which won't work with your RegEx. Any idea?

Comment: Ask a new question if the situation changed. Whoever sees it first will help answer

Answer (score 0):

For the 4th case in my question, this is the solution I came up with:

```
df['street'] = df.address.str.split('\d', expand=True)[0]
df['house_number'] = df.address.str.split('.(?=\d)', n=1, expand=True)[1]
```

So the logic for the street is simply everything prior to the first number in the string. For the house number, I split from the character left from the 1st digit found, and limit the split to 2 parts (part 0 & 1, thats why n=1 instead of 2 for 2 parts).